How is a BJT in the active region able to vary collector current without depending on the collector and emitter resistances?
I'm currently struggling with the idea of Ic = β x Ib as applied to BJTs. I am not understanding how a relationship like this is possible without accounting for collector and emitter resistances. At a certain base current and collector current, if I had to change the collector resistance, causing no change to the base current, and the transistor remains in the active region, the relation Ic = β x Ib would lead me to believe that the collector current would remain the same, but this obviously cannot be the case. What am I not understanding?
Thank you.

"What am I not understanding?" Most everything. There are textbooks with the word microelectronics somewhere in their titles that might help reduce what you don't know. It's a start. But to keep it simple, the active mode base current is an consequence of the physics. Not the cause. The voltage between base and emitter is the cause of the collector current. The base current is just needed to replenish carriers in the thin base. See this for many useful details to know. It confirms what I just wrote.

Why do you say that collector current remaining the same cannot be the case? It can remain the same, and as you say, as long as the transistor stays in the active region it will remain the same. Why do you say it obviously cannot?

I say "obviously" because my intuition tells me that if collector resistance is increased, collector current should decrease all other variables kept constant (base current). I suppose I'm struggling with the exact mechanism that ensures current remains constant given a certain base current in the active region, without any abstractions that are commonly used to explain what is really happening.

What does "collector resistance is increased [but ...] all other variables kept constant" mean? You could change the geometry of the transistor, or its chemistry, or the voltage or current you're applying to it, but I don't know how to change only the collector resistance without changing anything else.


the relation Ic = β x Ib would lead me to believe that the collector current would remain the same, but this obviously cannot be the case. What am I not understanding?

Consider the standard characteristic curve for a BJT: -

Image from Bipolar Junction Transistors (BJTs).

Y axis is collector current
X axis is collector-emitter voltage
Individual plots are for different base currents
Look at the X axis in the middle (\$V_{CE} = 3 \text{ volts}\$)
Move your eye up to (say) the 2.5 mA base current trace
Collector current is about 410 mA

Now, if the CE voltage changed upwards or downwards by decent amounts, the collector current pretty much remains at 410 mA. This implies that beta is around 164 across a swathe of different CE voltages.
If you now used a 5 volt supply in series with a variable resistor across collector and emitter, you can do a thought-experiment (base current held at 2.5 mA).

If the resistor was zero, the collector current would be around 420 mA and the CE voltage would be 5 volts

However, If the resistor was 10 ohm, it would surely drop about 4.2 volts across it but, does that fit in with the curves above?
Look at what the collector current is when the CE voltage is 0.8 volts. It's still around 400 mA. This means that if a resistor in series with the collector was varied from 0 Ω to 10 Ω it would hardly change the collector current if the external supply is 5 volts.
For the addition of a variable emitter resistor it becomes more complex to visualize but, trust me; the above characterization image remains the back-bone to what happens and, the collector current remains constant.

How can we calculate the voltage drop across the resistor here without knowing the collector voltage  for a 10 ohm resistor? (Resistor Voltage = 5V - Collector Voltage). This is how I understood it, but I'm not sure. Should we think like this: We assume that the transistor is still operating in the active region and we say the collector current is about 420 mA. Then we calculate the voltage drop across the resistor (420 x 10 = 4.2V). And then we substitute the obtained collector-emitter voltage into the graph and check if our assumption is correct. Is this true or am I missing something?

@SerkanKaya: You can use guess-and-check iteration, or you can plot the operating curve of the resistor (it's a straight line, according to Ohm's Law, but when you plot against Vce it'll slope downward, because the resistor voltage is decreasing).  Then find the intersection.

@SerkanKaya lets not forget that the voltage on the collector of a BJT (given the range of betas in a batch and different nuances from different suppliers) means we might easily be a volt or two out so, precision isn't something you should expect or rely on.

This question is conceptual, and to answer it, you do not need to know the internals of the transistor, but rather its behavior.
When Rc changes
In the common-emitter configuration, think of the transistor as a dynamic resistor with varying resistance Rce that complements the collector resistance Rc so that their sum Rce + RC remains constant. So, if you increase Rc, the transistor will decrease Rce, and the current will not change. Thus the transistor acts as a current stabilizer.
When Re changes
In the common-collector configuration, the transistor behavior is modified by the negative feedback mechanism. Now the collector-emitter part of the transistor acts as another type of dynamic resistor Rce that keeps the ratio Re/(Re + Rce) = const. So, if you increase Re, the transistor will increase Rce as well so that the emitter voltage will not change. Thus the transistor acts here as a voltage stabilizer.

In the second example, in which region does the transistor operate: saturation or active?
In the first example, there is a limit value (zero) for the collector-emitter resistance, but in the second example, there seems to be no limit value. So, if I make the emitter resistor a very large value, such as 10M ohms, can the transistor still keep the emitter voltage constant by increasing the collector-emitter resistance of the transistor?

@Serkan Kaya, In both cases, and in general, the transistor must work in active mode. This means that there must be some, even small (several hundred mV) voltage between the collector and the emitter; or in terms of resistances, there must be some "resistance".  But I want to advise you to use the explanations through resistance only for internal use at the stage of intuitive understanding because they are not liked by specialists and educators (although they have no better explanations:-)

@Serkan Kaya, regarding your first comment above: When Re is very high (10 MΩ), the transistor "resistance" will enormously increase. The current will be very small. The transistor will still keep the emitter voltage constant but the load connected in parallel to Re has to be extremely high (open circuit). This configuration with negative feedback is known as "emitter follower". If you want, we can consider it.

After reading your comment, I try to simulate the circuit in Proteus. Indeed, the emitter voltage is constant. However, I found these parts strange: normally, in an NPN BJT transistor, the collector current flows into the transistor, satisfying the formula IE = IC + IB. But according to the simulation result, the collector current is flowing out of the transistor. The collector current is approximately equal to the base current, and the emitter current is a small number. In this case, is transistor still operating in the active mode? Or which mode is transistor entering?

@Serkan Kaya, I can't figure out what this is, obviously some kind of bug. Why don't you simulate it here with CircuitLab, it's fast?

I finally understand what I missed. I have set up a wrong circuit instead of emitter follower circuit. When I built a pre-made circuit for the emitter follower from the google, I finally got the result I expected. Thank you so much for your help.

The following is a very brief description of how the bipolar transistor works:

A voltage of about Vbe=0.7 volts (npn case) effective between base and emitter further reduces the width of the depletion zone (pn junction) in the base region, which is  already very thin from the beginning (Vbe=0).

As a result, an electron current goes from the emitter through the base region (emitter current Ie, basic principle of a pn-diode) and - accelerated and attracted by the positive potential at the collector node - forms the collector current Ic.

It is relatively unimportant whether the collector potential is 2 or 5 or 8 volts greater than the potential at the base. Therefore, the current Ic is relatively independent of the voltage Vce (as long as Vce exceeds a minimum value of app. 1 volt.

Therefore, any voltage variation at the collector node (caused by changing the collector resistor Rc or by varying the supply voltage) will have only minor influence on the current Ic.

As a "side effect", a small portion of Ie goes to the base connection (Ib=Ie-Ic). That means: The expression Ib=Ic/B describes the fact that Ib is a - more or less - fixed percentage of Ic, but it does not contain any information about cause and effect.


Perhaps this can help to clarify the situation?

Andy's answer is much more comprehensive than mine here, but a simple demonstration by simulation will no doubt help. Here I connect a voltage source directly between emitter and collector, and I set base current to 1mA with a current source:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Here is a plot of collector current as I sweep V1 from 0 to 15V:

Collector current varies from 140mA to 170mA or so, changing very little, even as \$V_{CE}\$ changes wildly. This represents a current gain \$\beta\$ going from 140 to 170. It's usually assumed \$\beta\$ is constant, but it clearly varies a little.
That aside, you said that obviously collector current can't remain constant, but I say obviously it does, to a great extent.
We can modify the circuit to sweep collector resistance, instead of \$V_{CE}\$ directly, which would have a similar effect of causing \$V_{CE}\$ to vary over a wide range, but we'll see a similar invariance in \$I_C\$:

simulate this circuit
This is collector current \$I_C\$ while V1 remains constant but \$R_C\$ changes from 10Ω to 100Ω:

Again, the small dependence of \$\beta\$ on \$V_{CE}\$ notwithstanding, \$I_C\$ stays around 140mA, which you'd expect for a transistor with stated \$\beta\approx 140\$.

Many physical "laws" are approximations which don't precisely how describe how things behave, but provide a practical way of estimating things that would be hard to model precisely.  By way of analogy, consider a coil compression spring.  If placed under a small amount of compressive load, it will deflect by a certain amount.  If placed under roughly twice as much load, it will deflect by about double that amount.  In many cases, it may be useful to characterize springs (as well as many other objects) as having a "coefficient of elasticity".  This value, however, is only meaningful within a certain range of motion.  If a spring is compressed too far, additional force may cause some slight additional deflection, but not nearly as much as the coefficient of elasticity would suggest.  Indeed, the notion of a coefficient of elasticity may be essentially meaningless in such cases.
Many devices that would allow one amp of current to flow through it when one volt of potential is applied across it, would allow half an amp to flow through if only half a volt were applied, or would allow two amps to flow through if two volts were applied.  It's useful to describe all such devices as having a resistance of "one ohm", but that doesn't mean that every device which lets one amp through when one volt is applied would behave the same way.  Some devices may qualitatively change their behavior in response to an applied potential, much like a spring may "bottom out".  While one might view the coefficient of elasticity as radically changing when the spring bottoms out, it may be more useful to recognize that the ratio of applied force to deflection isn't really meaningful in such cases.

I think all this can be said in just two words - "non-linear resistance".

@Circuitfantasist: Many devices have operating regions within which they pass an amount of current which is substantial, but relatively unaffected by voltage, or in which their voltage drop is substantial but relatively unaffected by current.  One might try to compute the "resistance" of such devices within those operating regions, but if increasing the current through a diode from 700mA to 8A would increase the voltage drop from 0.7V to 0.8 V, I don't think it would be useful to describe that behavior by saying its resistance dropped tenfold from 1 ohm to 0.1 ohm.

It helps me to get rid of the simple R=V/I relation between voltage and current in simple resistors which we are exposed to for so long. In my head it made sense to think that if the voltage is increased between two points, there should naturally be an increase in current due to a strengthened electric field. So first being met with components where increased voltage does little to current was rather off putting - I think this is the reason for most of my uncertainty.
